# Read html template from assets crashes in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I switched from **angular `7`** to **angular `8.1`**

In **7** I read an html template file from assets like:

```
import bodyTemplate from '../../../assets/HTMLTemplates/contactMessage.html';
```

I have tried this in angular **8** and it gives me an error:

> ERROR in src/app/views/contact/contact.component.ts:9:26 - error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module
>   '../../../assets/HTMLTemplates/contactMessage.html'.

Background switch angular from 7 to 8

Comment: check your file path again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi usually assets folder should be right under you `src` folder and import should be something like this `import bodyTemplate from './assets/HTMLTemplates/contactMessage.html';` but from i see you are trying to import a html file ? why would you do that ?
Inside assets folder usually you put fonts, images and icons or css.

[image] 
 
Also don't forget in `angular.json`  `architect -> build -> options -> assets` to add path to assets folder.
[image]

Comment: Where should I store html templates (e.g. to compose an email) and how should I load it to a variable? Import now seems to accept only modules in Angular 8

Comment: You can't create html pages on the fly, read about Angular concepts and SPA (single page application) because this is very different from react, solution for you question may be for example you create html template with all html and css and then save on server and when user access different url you can return different email templates or different page, angular is rendering all pages in one file and that is `index.html`. I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is to build a mail body in Typescript.
My template contains the English version.
Depending on selected other language, I replace the English words by selected language words.

Like:

  sendEmail() {
    let body = bodyTemplate;

    body = body.replace(
      '[mainTitle.title]',
      this.translate.instant('mainTitle.title')
    );
....

Comment: Try this 
``<div innerHTML="this.email.body"> </div>``